# How can I disable deeplinks aka when opening a link, it doesn't redirect to an app but goes to mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, ios, browser, mobile-safari

So I am running an ad and I need the potential customer to reach a very specific page. However, when clicking on the ad, it redirects to the mobile app, therefore breaking the path I want the user to take.

Is there a way to add some code that will always direct the user to the mobile browser version rather than the app if they have it installed on their smartphone?

I had a look around but all the solutions find how to bring the person to the app. I want the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

make the link in your ads different from that which you need to open in app

like `example.com/add` and other links as `example.com/*` and in regex trying do something like this `/^((?!example.com/add).)*$/s`

Comment: Hi @vinil-prabhu! Thank you for your reply. I have never heard of regex before (thank you for letting me know about it), if it was placed in like html would it be like 

    <form action="/^((?!example.com/add).)*$/s">
    <input type="submit" value="Click Here To Claim" />
    </form>

this?

Comment: for deep linking where are you specifying your url ?

Comment: It will be a landing page that redirects to amazon. However, some users have the link automatically open in their app if they look at it on a phone and therefore break the link. I want the link to open in a web browser without fail.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. My understanding is that deeplinking is when the link opens in an app automatically.

Comment: Yes while specifying your url exclude a path to ads so that it should not open in app